# How to pay for Facebook marketing campaigns via API to run ads created via FB's marketing API?

Tags: api, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-marketing-api

I am trying to create, manage and pay for Facebook marketing campaigns all via APIs. How can I set up the payment methods for those campaigns that I have created thru Facebook marketing API? Is there a popup dialog or an endpoint that can accept and/or store a payment method in facebook for these campaigns to bill the charges so that I can run the ads? I don't want to explicitly open any facebook's UI only to set up the payment methods. A popup dialog or a redirect would be fine.

Please guide me, I am lost in their documentations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the solution. You need to include and use Facebook Javascript SDK and call the FB.ui() on an event. This function will take three properties and a callback.

```
<script>
function triggerPaymentDialog(){
  FB.ui({
      account_id: ‘<ACCOUNT-ID>’,
      display: 'popup',
      method: 'ads_payment',
      },
      function(response) {
       // use response 
       // if (response && !response.error_message).......
      }
    }
  );
}
</script>
```

It will open a popup on top of your app that will flow the user to either use any existing payment method on file with facebook or let the user add a new payment method to pay for campaigns.

Further details can be found here
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-apis/guides/javascript-ads-dialog-for-payments/